# #selector unresolved identifier function

Tags: swift

In the init function the #selector can't seem to find the calling function.

Here is the class

```
import UIKit

protocol ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {
func toggleSection(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int)
}

class ExpandableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
var delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate?
var section: Int!

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

  override init(reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectHeaderView(_:))))

}

@objc func selectHeaderView(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let cell = gesture.view as! ExpandableHeaderView
    delegate?.toggleSection(header: self, section: cell.section)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectHeaderView(_:))))
}


func custonInt(title: String, section: Int, delegate:   ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate){

    self.titleLabel.text = title
    self.section = section
    self.delegate = delegate
}

override func layoutSubviews(){
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
}
```

}

Here is the error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'selectHeaderView'
```

the init function add gesture recognizer can't find selectHeaderView. Its acting as if its not part of the class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectHeaderView(_:))))
```

to:

```
self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectHeaderView(gesture:))))
```

Comment: Or just `#selector(selectHeaderView)`

Answer (score 0):

Your class indeed has no method called `selectHeaderView(_:)`. `selectHeaderView(_:)`. Your class *does* have a method `selectHeaderView(gesture:)`, however. Argument labels do matter in this situation. `_:` means no external argument label.

You should write

```
#selector(selectHeaderView(gesture:))
```

You can also let Swift decide the argument labels

```
#selector(selectHeaderView)
```